# UITextView Content Width shrinks as Height grows while typing. Why am I seeing this behavior?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

In the UITextView delegate method I am printing its Frame and Content Size as I type in it.

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
     {   
               NSLog(@"textView Frame: %@ Content Size:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame),NSStringFromCGSize(textView.contentSize));
               return YES;
      }
```

What I am seeing is very puzzling. The Content width keeps shrinking as its height grow with text scrolling up as I type. The frame of the textView remains same. Why am I seeing this behavior ?

```
2012-05-25 16:18:53.349  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{271, 74}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.405  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{270, 74}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.412  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{269, 74}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.508  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{268, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.516  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{267, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.613  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{266, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.621  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{265, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.684  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{264, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.709  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{263, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.789  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{262, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.813  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{261, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.868  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{260, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:53.949  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{259, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:54.029  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{258, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:54.045  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{257, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:54.173  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{256, 132}
2012-05-25 16:18:54.180  textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{255, 132}
.......
2012-05-25 16:19:00.420 textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{119, 1524}
2012-05-25 16:19:00.477 textView Frame: {{20, 12}, {65, 40}} Content Size:{118, 1582}
```

**EDIT:**
Few more details. 
When I create this textView, I am creating it with much larger frame size and scale it down and add it in it's superview. The reason I am doing this is so that when the textView's superview is zoomed, the text inside textView does not get blurred.

```
float Scale = 5.0;
CGRect rect = ... (original frame of myTextView)
myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,rect.size.width*Scale, rect.size.height*Scale)];
myTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/originalScale,1.0/originalScale);
```

That approach worked well but it seems its causing this bug. (because when I turned the scaling off, this problem does not happen).

Comment: You should return a `BOOL` if you implement this delegate method

Comment: Yes I do. I just forgot in this example.